# tRPC invalid hook call in react function component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, trpc.io

I am trying to create a new user when the user connects to the site with their wallet.

When the user clicks the button to connect, the `useAccount` hook will return an address of type string.

I then want to create a new user with this address in my database using tRPC.

Currently, I am getting invalid hook call errors.

When a user clicks the button, the authHandler method is called which then calls this hook:

```
//hook to get account info
const account = useAccount();

const { connectAsync } = useConnect({
    connector: new InjectedConnector(),
    onSuccess: () => handleSuccessfulConnection(),
    onError: () => handleConnectionError(),
  });
```

Then the onSuccess callback executes this:

```
const handleSuccessfulConnection = (): void => {
    const { data } = trpc.user.createUser.useMutation(account.address);
    //runtime error here about invalid hook call
    console.log(data);
    setShowSuccessToast(true);
  };
```

Any way I can resolve this issue?

Comment: You can't call hooks like `useMutation` inside a function, so that's the issue. I can't tell you how to resolve because I don't know what that hook does nor what `handleSuccessfulConnection` is trying to do.

Answer (score 6):

`useMutation` is a hook, so you can't call it conditionally. Once you create the mutation, you can use its `mutate` to fire it.

```
function MyComponent(props: {foo: boolean}) {
  const myMutation = trpc.router.query.useMutation();

  if (!props.foo) return null; // can't call hooks after this
  
  function handleClick() {
    myMutation.mutate(inputArgs);
  }

  return (
    <button onClick={handleClick}>Click me</button>
  )
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This work for me after 3 hours of debugging xD.

Comment: This is for the procedures using mutate. What about for those using query.